# JMeter using same extracted value for all Thread

Tags: jmeter

I have two sample request , One request response generate a frst json (Customer Validation ) with some date , payment reference (unique for every run) and status. The next request (MakePayment) is to use the payment reference in the first request as a body and then post to make payment . 
I have used Reqular Expression and bean Shell to extract and post . This is working when  i used one thread to run while executing .

The issue now is this .. i want to run a load test for 50 Threads , each thread is going to return unique payment reference and each of them should be used in the next request . Currently what i have written is using the first extracted value for all the next thread which make only one work as the reference cannot be used for 2 request . 49 will fail .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPklQ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGW39.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPDXl.png)

If i run with 50 , Threads, The first request will generate 1 unique reference each in response. i want to use each of them in the Make Payment threads. Currently its just using one of the reference for all the Make Payment Request

Answer (score 0):

1. JMeter Properties are **global** for the whole JVM, you need to make the property specific to the thread
2. [Since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) language for scripting
3. [Never inline JMeter functions or variables into scripts](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)
4. It's better to use [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor) for getting the values from JSON responses

---

1. Change your Beanshell Assertion to [JSR223 Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) and use the following code there:

   ```
   props.put('payment_reference_' + (ctx.getThreadNum() + 1), vars.get('payment_reference'))
   ```
2. In your "Make Payment Request" use [__P()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) and [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) functions combination in order to get the thread-specific value like:

   ```
   ${__P(payment_reference_${__threadNum},)}
   ```